# Lowering pixel quality in Sentinel5P-CH4

Tags: google-earth-engine, data-collection, sentinel-5p

I'm working with CH4 product Sentinel-5p provided by ESA Copernicus.
I need to change the pixel quality. Currently, GEE only data are used with a quality
assurance value (qa_value) > 0.5, but that takes away a lot of data from certain regions.
The code is:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4')
  .select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-07-16');

var band_viz = {
  min: 1750,
  max: 1900,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'S5P CH4');
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*that takes away a lot of data from certain regions*?"

Comment: There is probably a reason the data provider used that QA threshold, don't think you can do anything about it in GEE. You could try and download the original data from the provider directly or use a larger time window such that the gaps are more likely to be filled